# Want to check system availability in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am converting an old .bat script to a PowerShell script which will basically go and deliver a file to systems on the network and then tell me who has been missed. I have looked online, but I cannot find an example of code that will essentially check to see if the system is available and if its not then skip it.I have listed the line below that I am trying to convert;

if not exsist\%1\c$ goto :skip

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ping it, if it responds, do a:

```
if(Test-Path \\machine.name\c$){
  #it's available
}
```

Comment: Will that skip it if the result does not equal "#it's available" ?

Comment: What do you mean? If test-path returns true, it means is can find the drive of whatever machine.name is and will execute whatever code is in the IF statement.

Comment: Oh, I see.Thank you very much for your help, still very new to PowerShell.